# Ali Baba and the 10 thieves

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, river-crossing

> **EDIT:** This puzzle originates from the "International Mathematics Tournament of the Towns", and was published in the book "S.M.A.R.T circle overview" by [Professor Andy Liu](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/Liu_A.html). The author has (albeit a little retroactively) [granted us the permission](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42153887#42153887) to use the puzzle.

Ten thieves, ranked A to J, are trying to cross a river in a boat requiring
two rowers. Unfortunately, if the ranks of any two in the boat differ by
more than 1, those two will refuse to stay in the boat. This constraint
means they can’t get across the river. Their leader, with a rank of A, asks
Ali Baba for help and Ali Baba replies, “If you give me a rank of A, equal
to yours, we can all cross the river.” The leader agrees.

How many one-way
crossings are the least required to get Ali Baba and the 10 thieves across
the river?

NOTE:

> More than 2 people can accumulate in the boat. Boat is operated by 2
>   rowers. So a single person cannot row it on his own.

Comment: There is a need to have 2 rowers to move the boat ? Or can it be moved by only one ?

Comment: @Sanea A single rower is not allowed.

Comment: Is there some lateral-thinking ? I can't think how H-I-J can be on the same boat whatsoever

Comment: @Sanea Nope. Just a more furnished variant of Lion, Goat, Grass river crossing puzzle.

Comment: I have the feeling that there may be also some Hanoï tower problem variant in here...

Comment: How very clever of Ali Baba. By symmetry, rank of J would have worked just as well.

Comment: @Bass any rank works but some works better then others, for example if Ali baba would be ranked as E, the answer was going to be shorter. Since he can both travel with D , E and F, instead of just A and B.

Comment: @ifyalciner, very true, the method works for any rank, but the optimality proof requires either A or J.

Comment: Where are the remaining 30? ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here’s my **quadruple-checked, optimality-guaranteed solution** with

> 33 crossings.

(Glorfindel’s initial answer had the same crossing count earlier, but UselessInfoMine discovered an error in that method. The updated version of that method works, but uses 4 crossings more than the optimal method.)

You can get any 2 consecutive thieves over like this

> +Aab, -ab, +bc, -Ab, +Aab, -bc, +XY, -Aa (8 moves)

Repeat four times, always bringing the two lowest ranked thieves over.  Bring the rest over with the final move.

If there’s a quicker way to do it, it must be Very Clever Indeed, since

> The only move that adds a thief on the opposite shore is the +Aab, which cannot happen more often than every fourth move. (Barring the silly -Aab waste of move, of course.)
>  Given that the final +Aab will bring 3 guys, a total of 9 +Aab’s are required, and in between them, there will have to be at minimum 8x3 other crossings. This sums up to a minimum of 33 moves.

Therefore, barring lateral thinking and other trick answers, this solution is optimal.

Comment: This is the right answer,. But I have 2 questions: How do you guarantee optimality? And if you are sure that this is optimal, why do you say that "if there is a quicker way,... it must be very clever". If this is optimal shouldn't there be no shorter way?

Comment: @ifyalciner, I added the remaining two sentences to the optimality proof. I thought they were self-evident, but of course I failed to appreciate the fact that anyone reading the answer probably didn’t just spend a couple of hours on this puzzle. Should be clearer now.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution with

> 37 crossings.

Explanation:

> AAB, AB return
>  BC, AB return
>  C has now crossed.
>  AAB, BC return
>  CD, AA return
>  AAB, AA return
>  BCD have now crossed.
>  EF, BC return
>  AAB, AB return
>  BC, AB return
>  CDEF have now crossed, after 16 crossings.

> GH, CD return
>  IJ, EF return
>  GHIJ have now crossed.

> Repeat the procedure in the first block.
>  CDEFGHIJ have now crossed, after 2x16 + 4 = 36 crossings.
>  The final crossing is by AAB.

Comment: @Bass when I started working on a solution, I counted two-way crossings. I had to edit my original solution and was still counting that way. But now it's correct (I think).

Comment: I finally spotted the reason you upped the move count. Pesky B jumping over the river, confusing honest people like that. Kind of interesting that the error resulted in exactly the optimal (by my reasoning, at least) crossing count though.

Comment: This seems to be turning into a rather interesting social experiment: as of late, this answer has been getting *more* upvotes than the correct one right below it. Someone even bruteforced the problem and posted the same solution without looking at any of the other answers than the highest voted one.

Comment: @Bass it's some kind of [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/295232). I agree your answer is better but there's not much I can do about it.

Comment: Oh, there’s even an acronym for that effect, I thought I was on to something new and interesting. :-)

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: UselessInfoMine noticed that Glorfindel’s seemingly optimal solution didn’t actually work. [Here’s a working version with the same crossing count](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58536/36023).

—————

Glorfindel’s approach seems good. Here’s a lateral-thinking solution within the established parameters of the story. First, observe that

> 1. The leader can change Ali Baba’s rank at will.
>  2. The other thieves will accept Ali’s new rank, no matter high Ali is promoted.

Abusing those observations,

> give Ali Baba a new rank for each crossing. Each trip over the river will take 2 thieves+Ali, the other thief will return with Ali.

This allows everybody to cross in mere

> 17 crossings. Each round-trip deposits a thief on the other shore. After 8 round trips, there are only two thieves left, so everyone fits on the boat.

Comment: If you really want to abuse those observations, why would they apply just to Ali Baba, and not to the rest of the thieves?

Comment: @Acccumulation, well, sure, but it wasn’t established in the flavour story that the leader can give new ranks to the other thieves.

Comment: If you are going to [Loophole Abuse](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LoopholeAbuse) with "lateral thinking", you might as well take it [Up To Eleven](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UpToEleven) and finish it off in one crossing: Alibaba and the leader beat up all the other thieves one by one, tie them up with a big rope and throw them on the boat, or even "better" Alibaba and the leader kill all the other thieves ... because the puzzle doesn't state that the thieves have to make it *alive* across the river.

Comment: @maskedman, I’d like to think there’s a marked difference between (ab)using the elements that are already established as being possible within the story, and inventing a boat long enough to serve as a bridge.

Comment: @bass Uhm, ok, not sure which universe you come from, in my universe, it is not unusual, and certainly not "impossible", for *thieves* to beat up or kill people. In fact, I suspect that it would be more common for the leader of the gang of thieves to do something like that if the other thieves throw stupid tantrums like I don't want to be on the boat with this guy or that guy.

Comment: @maskedman, I’m not absolutely certain which universe I’m from, either, but I’m pretty sure it isn’t the one that has Ali Baba in it.

Answer (score 2):

I make it

> 57 - and I think @Glorfindel has managed to leave B on the wrong bank in his first block.

I'm sat at work, so my brain isn't fully on this, but

> Ali, the leader and one other would make it in one crossing, AAB.
> Ali, the leader and two thieves make it in 5, adding four to the original single crossing.
> Adding a third thief adds another four to make 9 crossings.
> The fourth and fifth both add six crossings each for 15 and 21, the sixth and seventh both add eight for 29 and 37, and the ninth and tenth each add ten for 47 and 57.

The Crossing list is:

> 1) CDEFGHIJ  AAB  _ Out
> 2) CDEFGHIJ  AB  A Back
> 3) ADEFGHIJ  BC  A Out
> 4) ADEFGHIJ  AB  C Back
> 5) DEFGHIJ  AAB  C Out
> 6) DEFGHIJ  BC  AA Back
> 7) BEFGHIJ  CD  AA Out
> 8) BEFGHIJ  AA  CD Back
> 9) EFGHIJ  AAB  CD Out
> 10) EFGHIJ  CD  AAB Back
> 11) CFGHIJ  DE  AAB Out
> 12) CFGHIJ  AB  ADE Back
> 13) AFGHIJ  BC  ADE Out
> 14) AFGHIJ  AB  CDE Back
> 15) FGHIJ  AAB  CDE Out
> 16) FGHIJ  DE  AABC Back
> 17) DGHIJ  EF  AABC Out
> 18) DGHIJ  BC  AAEF Back
> 19) BGHIJ  CD  AAEF Out
> 20) BGHIJ  AA  CDEF Back
> 21) GHIJ  AAB  CDEF Out
> 22) GHIJ  EF  AABCD Out
> 23) EHIJ  FG  AABCD Back
> 24) EHIJ  CD  AABFG Back
> 25) CHIJ  DE  AABFG Out
> 26) CHIJ  AB  ADEFG Back
> 27) AHIJ  BC  ADEFG Out
> 28) AHIJ  AB  CDEFG Back
> 29) HIJ  AAB  CDEFG Out
> 30) HIJ  FG  AABCDE Back
> 31) FIJ  GH  AABCDE Out
> 32) FIJ  DE  AABCGH Back
> 33) DIJ  EF  AABCGH Out
> 34) DIJ  BC  AAEFGH Back
> 35) BIJ  CD  AAEFGH Out
> 36) BIJ  AA  CDEFGH Back
> 37) IJ  AAB  CDEFGH Out
> 38) IJ  GH  AABCDEF Back
> 39) GJ  HI  AABCDEF Out
> 40) GJ  EF  AABCDHI Back
> 41) EJ  FG  AABCDHI Out
> 42) EJ  CD  AABFGHI Back
> 43) CJ  DE  AABFGHI Out
> 44) CJ  AB  ADEFGHI Back
> 45) AJ  BC  ADEFGHI Out
> 46) AJ  AB  CDEFGHI Back
> 47) J  AAB  CDEFGHI Out
> 48) J  HI  AABCDEFG Back
> 49) H  IJ  AABCDEFG Out
> 50) H  FG  AABCDEIJ Back
> 51) F  GH  AABCDEIJ Out
> 52) F  DE  AABCGHIJ Back
> 53) D  EF  AABCGHIJ Out
> 54) D  BC  AAEFGHIJ Back
> 55) B  CD  AAEFGHIJ Out
> 56) B  AA  CDEFGHIJ Back
> 57) _  AAB  CDEFGHIJ Out

Comment: If I could get the interface to list in a spoiler, I'd list the crossings.

Comment: Aha! It actually tells you on the editing page. :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting my mistake. Fortunately, it's easily corrected, requiring only 4 extra crossings.

Answer (score 1):

Lateral thinking answer: It can be done in

> One trip. AAB in the boat, the other 8 in the water holding on to the sides, since they refuse to stay *in* the boat together.

Comment: This particular solution might be implicitly forbidden, though: If this solution works, then it would also have worked without promoting Ali Baba. This contradicts the question, which states that the constraint originally prevents them from crossing the river.

Comment: @Bass ah, but only Ali is strong enough to row a boat with so many thieves hanging on it.

Answer (score 0):

> 33 steps

To be honest, I was trying to validate @Glorfindel answer with logic programming, but it came up with a shorter one

Everyone is on the left initially, trying to cross to the right side, 
the rightmost parameter is time step

> cross(AAB,right,0)
> cross(AB,left,1)
> cross(BC,right,2)
> cross(AB,left,3)
> //C crossed
> cross(AAB,right,4)
> cross(AA,left,5)
> cross(IJ,right,6)
> cross(BC,left,7)
> //IJ crossed,  C crossed back
> cross(AAB,right,8)
> cross(AB,left,9)
> cross(BC,right,10)
> cross(AB,left,11)
> //C crossed
> cross(AAB,right,12)
> cross(BC,left,13)
> cross(CD,right,14)
> cross(AA,left,15)
> //D crossed
> cross(AAB,right,16)
> cross(BC,left,17)
> cross(GH,right,18)
> cross(AA,left,19)
> //GH crossed, C crossed back
> cross(AAB,right,20)
> cross(AB,left,21)
> cross(BC,right,22)
> cross(AB,left,23)
> //C crossed
> cross(AAB,right,24)
> cross(BC,left,25)
> cross(EF,right,26)
> cross(AA,left,27)
> //EF crossed, C back
> cross(AAB,right,28)
> cross(AB,left,29)
> cross(BC,right,30)
> cross(AB,left,31)
> //C crossed
> cross(AAB,right,32)
> //All crossed

Answer (score -3):

It can all be done in

> a single crossing

By

> putting all the thieves in the boat in one trip. Ali Baba just wanted to be head thief for a little while.

Comment: Very clever, I suppose. How did they work around the limitation that B refuses to share a boat with D,E,F etc.?

Comment: Well, not really, since C won’t go with either of the As.

Comment: Drat. Thought I was being cute by exploiting the fact that there's no maximum on the boat's capacity, but it turns out there is a maximum on the boat's capacity thanks to the rank rule.

Comment: @Bass I noticed my mistake just after the time limit on editing that comment expired.

Comment: The rules are not well expressed- the OP never says that A and C are 2 ranks apart and similar- he really should have said the ranks are from 1, 2...11 and show the numerical separation.