# Is Ron a mathematical prodigy?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers

I and Ron were talking casually over coffee. Just then a thought sprung into my mind; could there exist numbers such that if their digits are reversed, for example $123\to321$, the new number is exactly double the original?

> **NOTE: I am talking about integers excluding 0 (Thanks! Bass)**

Ron replied, "***Of course there are!***"

After two seconds of silence,

Ron added, "***But the smallest such number is 18 digits long.***"

When I asked him how did he know, he assured me that it was nothing more than 4th grade maths.

> **How did Ron deduce this?**

Comment: And mention if you are using base 10. "Digit" on its own is meaningless.

Comment: @MartinArgerami "Digit" on its own *means* base 10 in standard usage. If other bases are envisioned then this should be clearly stated.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree, and yet an answer that claims “Since there are no rules on which base you use…” has 12 votes at the moment. So specifying the base in the question would indeed have been good IMO.

Comment: First sentence. Ron and I. :)

Comment: I didn't check Bass' claim that such a number does not exist. But, this rings a bell!!! IIRC the closely related puzzle asking about the numbers that gets doubled when you move its least sigfnificant digit to the most significant position actually has 18 digits. Friends at the math department asked me that once, so I worked it out. That number is
$$n=105263157894736842=2\cdot\frac{10^{18}-1}{19}.$$ You get $2n$ simply by moving that trailing $2$ to the front. There are other solutions but this is the smallest.

Comment: @JohnColeman The word "Digit" only defines a number below 10. It does not imply a base whatsoever. Hence the usage of the word in the following sentence I borrowed from the internet: "The base-2 numeral system is a positional notation with a radix of 2. Each digit is referred to as a bit." Though I do agree that my answer does not answer the question directly, to me it seems like a valid try to solve the problem stated especially since a number like that does not exist in the decimal numeral system.

Comment: Did anyone else click on this because they thought it was a question about Harry Potter?

Comment: @RickvanOsta How does the existence of non-standard usage refute a claim about standard usage? When used without qualification in a context where other bases are not under consideration the phrase "3-digit number" *means* a number between one hundred and a nine hundred ninety nine. There are, of course, other bases out there, and for such number systems there is a nonstandard usage whereby "digit" denotes a number between 0 and the base minus 1. In the hexadecimal system "C" is a "digit", but it is clearly not standard English usage to refer to "C" as a digit.

Comment: @JohnColeman No one said that "Standard English usage" is applied here, nor was there any mention of what base to use. Also, the definition of a "3-digit number" is a number that consists of 3 digits, nothing more, nothing less. Also, note how I explicitly defined the standard that I was using in my answer. If you don't appreciate out-of-the-box answers or the like, feel free to downvote and move on.

Comment: @RickvanOsta Even for [tag:lateral-thinking] puzzles—which this is NOT—the solver is not given free license to invent their own rules, nor to use arbitrary interpretations of the words or phrases of the problem statement that go outside their customary meanings. Especially for puzzles not tagged "lateral thinking", the right answer to a puzzle will be the one that uses what the puzzle gave you or hinted at, without inventing facts, rules, or interpretations out of thin air to make a "solution" work. Puzzle posters can't close every loophole… and shouldn't have to.

Comment: @Rubio Normally I'd agree with you, except there is no valid solution to this puzzle without bending the rules a little.

Comment: If we allow bases other than 10, then 1012 base 3 is a solution (without any leading zero issues) so the problem still doesn't work as stated.

Comment: This sounds like a misquoted version of this puzzle: https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/07/23/what-number-doubles-when-its-last-digit-becomes-its-first-digit-sunday-puzzle/

Comment: The wording of the problem is quite noteworthy: it's the perfect setup for a non-existence proof. The asker makes it clear he doesn't know the answer and just thought up the question, and all the given data comes from an outsider, whom we have no particular reason to trust, in fact the claims he makes and the calculations he's supposed to have made in two seconds are an ample clue as to his trustworthiness.  Definitely going to steal the technique if I ever need to make such a puzzle myself. (@jmoriarty, yeah, almost certainly, but who cares as long as the resulting puzzle is excellent)

Comment: prog_SAHIL - your question here explicitly asks "How did Ron deduce this?" but given the answers, which seem unarguably to reject the possibility of any solution, the only defensible answer appears to be "By mistake - he's wrong!" - but that doesn't make a very satisfying puzzle.  Other evidence suggests you have misstated a different puzzle entirely. It's no longer clear what you intended to ask, let alone what an answerer would have to say here to be considered "correct" ... I think you're either going to have to edit the puzzle, or see it closed as **Unclear what you're asking**.

Answer (score 24):

We know two things about the number:

> A: If you reverse it and divide by 2, you get the original number
>  B: If you multiply it by 2 and reverse it, you get the original number again.

Deducing from there,

> * From A, the first digit must be even, otherwise the reversed number wouldn't be divisible by 2
>  * From B, the first digit must be < 5, otherwise the doubled number would have too many digits (a number with leading zeroes would be ill-formed, so we exclude those straight away)
>  **So the first digit must be either 2 or 4.**
>  * From B, the last digit must be either twice the first digit (if the second digit <5), or one more than that (if the second digit >= 5). (*We can omit the usual "modulo 10" bit here, because our numbers are smaller than 5*)
>  * If the first digit is 2, then the last digit must be 4 or 5. However, using A, we get a number ending in 2, divided by 2; the result must end in either 6 or 1. **So 2 cannot be the first digit**.
>  * If the first digit is 4, the last digit must be either 8 or 9.
>  Again using A, a number ending in 4 divided by 2 will end in either 2 or 7. **So 4 cannot be the first digit either**

It would seem that Ron must have used the single-phase Stetson-Milliner method, because

> apart from the trivial 0, such a number doesn't exist at all, and Ron totally pulled his answer out of a hat.

(Hope I didn't make any mistakes there; tried to double-check, but it's difficult to proofread one's own logic because one becomes blind to any flaws.)

Comment: I agree with your statement A. But if a number shows this property(say N), will 2N also show this property?

Comment: @prog_sahil, Count again. That number doubles when you shift the last digit to the beginning, and you stole it from a youtube video.

Comment: Can you please link the video?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL, just google ”which number doubles when reversed” like I did after posting my answer. The [top result](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/07/23/what-number-doubles-when-its-last-digit-becomes-its-first-digit-sunday-puzzle/) is the solution to another puzzle whose result you posted in your (now-deleted) comment.

Comment: But this puzzle is a lot different from that one.

Comment: Yes, it is. Somehow, that answer also has 18 digits, and somehow, you thought it solved this puzzle. There are very few scenarios where those coincidences are likely. Also, I happened to find the [uncredited source](https://page-one.live.cf.public.springer.com/pdf/preview/10.1007/978-3-319-56823-2_1) of your [recent river-crossing problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58524/ali-baba-and-the-10-thieves), identical even up to the protagonist's name. These comments are probably not the right place to sort this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71343/discussion-between-prog-sahil-and-bass).

Comment: "From B, the first digit must be < 5, otherwise the doubled number would have too many digits" is not necessarily true. Take, for example, 75: (75 * 2 = 150) → (051 = 51)

Comment: @Vaelus, the very next sentence discounts numbers starting with 0, since that's not how you write numbers. But if you insist on allowing such misspelled numbers: a number with the first digit greater than 4 must end in a 5 or a 0 to restore the digit count. Doubling such a number always results in a number starting with 1. Reversing that number will give you a number ending in 1. So such numbers are impossible.

Comment: I think that further explanation should go in the answer. Not starting with a number that begins with zero is an obvious choice, but not allowing numbers that end with zero (so that they start with zero when reversed) is dubious.

Comment: @Vaelus, mm, possibly. On the other hand, the answer is now "hygienic" in that it follows every usual convention, and as such, doesn't invite out-of-the-box solutions like "maybe it's not base-10" or "if you reverse the number 2, it kind of looks like a 5". I agree that the case where the doubled number ends in zero is much more important than those, but this comment section seems to be just the proper place for that proof. (The commentary is also where I'd put that proof if I were to publish the solution as an article. That, or a footnote.)

Answer (score 14):

Since there are no rules on which base you use:

> If you were to do this in base-2, or binary, the number 01 (1) would become 10 (2), which doubles it's value. :D

Comment: The stated example limits to at least Base 4 so yours is excluded.

Comment: And the example did not meets the "double" specification, so he can use whatever base he want.